# SQL query doesnt return all months

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, missing-data

I have a problem with showing dates

Table  *#dates* include only monts from 2 years ago to present in form (2018-01, 2018-02, 2018-03 etc.)
Table *QA_Ratio* include items and they count of production per month. Some month the item wasn´t produce (in *QA_Ratio* is NOT a record). But if I LEFT JOIN the #dates table to QA_Ratio, and filtred by specific item, there are still only months in produce and I want to show **every month** even without record (for example with NULL).
Here is code:

```
   Select
    #dates.frame
     ,Material 
     ,NG_qty 
     ,Ratio
    FROM QA_Ratio
    Left join #dates ON #dates.frame = QA_Ratio.frame COLLATE Czech_CI_AS
    Where Material = '3p326040-2 V'
Order by frame
```

This show

```
2018-05 3P326040-2 V        0   0
2018-06 3P326040-2 V        0   0
2018-07 3P326040-2 V        0   0
2018-08 3P326040-2 V        0   0
2018-09 3P326040-2 V        0   0
2018-10 3P326040-2 V        13  1
2018-11 3P326040-2 V        65  1
2018-12 3P326040-2 V        550 8
2019-01 3P326040-2 V        503 240
2019-02 3P326040-2 V        187 19
2019-03 3P326040-2 V        402 4
2019-04 3P326040-2 V        202 6
2019-07 3P326040-2 V        2   0
```

So there is not 2019-05 and 2019-06. How to include missing moths?

Thx

Comment: Material belongs to QA_Ratio

Comment: DBMS ... could be T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you need to take the #dates table and then join the QA_Ratio.

That way you get all the dates and NULL-s on the not joined rows.

Than we just format the results with the ISNULL in the select.

```
DECLARE @date_from  DATE =  '2018-01-01'
DECLARE @type       NVARCHAR(32) =  '3p326040-2 V'

SELECT
    frame       =   d.frame
,   Material    =   ISNULL(qar.Material , @type)
,   NG_qty      =   ISNULL(qar.NG_qty   , 0)
,   Ratio       =   ISNULL(qar.Ratio    , 0)
FROM    
                #dates      AS d
    LEFT JOIN   QA_Ratio    AS qar  ON  qar.frame = d.frame
                                    AND qar.Material = @type
WHERE   1 = 1
    AND d.frame >= @date_from
ORDER BY
    d.frame
```